# I am not getting exact response from my api as i am getting from chat gpt

Tags: reactjs, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-4

Can someone explain  why I am not getting good enough response. My 3.5 api is generating content that is good enough as gpt's response. my app is about helping recruiters to refine their job posts. but its not working fine. How can I improve the response?

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function App() {
  const [apiKey, setApiKey] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://server-khaki-kappa.vercel.app/api/key')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setApiKey(data.apiKey))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }, []);

  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
  };

  const personas = [
    'Lou Adler',
    'Stacy Donovan Zapa',
    'Johnny Campbell',
    'Greg Savage',
    'Maisha Cannon',
    'Glen Cathey'
  ];

  const styles = [
    'Captivating',
    'Enticing',
    'Witty',
    'Appealing',
    'Engaging',
    'Impactful',
    'Dynamic',
    'Exciting',
    'Professional'
  ];

  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState({
    system: '',
    user: '',
    assistant: '',
    prompt: '',
    model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo-16k',
    persona: 'Lou Adler',
    style: 'Captivating'
  });

  const [assistantResponse, setAssistantResponse] = useState('');
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const handleUserInput = (e) => {
    setUserInput(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }));
  };

  const sendUserInput = async () => {
    setLoading(true);

    const data = {
      model: userInput.model,
      messages: [
        {
          role: 'system',
          content: `You are an AI language model trained to assist recruiters in refining job posts and your name is recruiterGPT. do not generate a response if the job description and some requirements are not given, and ask for them. It assists users in generating human-like text based on the given instructions and context. think properly and take your time before answering. Here are the instructions: Assistant, please generate a ${userInput.style.toLowerCase()} and vibrant job description for the position. The goal is to rewrite the existing job description, emphasizing the benefits and opportunities associated with the role. Take on the persona of ${userInput.persona}, a recruitment expert, and create the content in a ${userInput.style.toLowerCase()}  style that will attract potential candidates. Present the information in a compelling manner while keeping the user's requirements in mind. Even if certain points are not present in the job description, mention them and create enthusiasm around them. These Points include: 1- Offer a Competitive Compensation and Benefits.
          2- Vibrant and collaborative team,
          3- Professional Development Opportunities.
          4- Work-Life Balance.
          5- Offering Challenging and Meaningful Work.
          6- Become part of our family. 7- Career Development Plan. Prioritize communicating what's in it for them. Emphasize more on benefits for them and highlight the benefits and gains they can expect from the job.Also write about the essential requirements and qualifications needed in detail. First emphasize on tonality and benefits and then generate refined requirements. Thank you!.
`
        },
        {
          role: 'user',
          content: `Take the persona of ${userInput.persona} and use a ${userInput.style.toLowerCase()} tonality when rewriting the following Job Description. In the job description emphasize what’s in it for them.First include Career Development, training and growth opportunities, work-life balance, competitive salary, challenging and meaningful work and a vibrant and collaborative team. More of the content should be around these points infact 68% of you response should be around benefits and what an employee can get from us. emphasize less on the requirements, but explain them after describing benefits. Display response in a Job Description format and include a few of the main responsibilities. Generate content no more than 3500 words, But more than 1000 words. ${userInput.prompt}. Note: If job description is not given in this prompt, ask for it and do not generate response until a job description is given by the user.`
        }
      ],
      temperature: 0.5,
      max_tokens: 2049,
    }; 

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions',
        data,
        { headers }
      );
      const { choices } = response.data;
      const assistantResponse = choices[0].message.content;
      setLoading(false);
      setAssistantResponse(assistantResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.message);
    }
  };

  const formatAssistantResponse = (response) => {
    const paragraphs = response.split('\n\n');

    const formattedResponse = paragraphs.map((paragraph, index) => (
      <p key={index} className="text-left mb-4">
        {paragraph}
      </p>
    ));

    return formattedResponse;
  };

  return (
    <div className="container mx-auto py-8">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Chat:</h1>
      {loading ? (
        <>
          <h1 className="spinner"></h1>
          <p>Dear user, Please be patient RecruitGpt is refining your post to its best....</p>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="bg-gray-100 p-4 mb-4">
            {formatAssistantResponse(assistantResponse)}
          </div>
        </>
      )}

      <section className="m-6">
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block mb-2">
            Model:
            <select
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
              name="model"
              value={userInput.model}
              onChange={handleUserInput}
            >
              <option value="gpt-3.5-turbo">gpt-3.5-turbo</option>
              <option value="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k">gpt-3.5-turbo-16k</option>
              <option value="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613">gpt-3.5-turbo-0613</option>
              <option value="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613">gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block mb-2">
            Persona:
            <select
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
              name="persona"
              value={userInput.persona}
              onChange={handleUserInput}
            >
              {personas.map((persona, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={persona}>{persona}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block mb-2">
            Style:
            <select
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
              name="style"
              value={userInput.style}
              onChange={handleUserInput}
            >
              {styles.map((style, index) => (
                <option key={index} value={style}>{style}</option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div className="mb-4">
          <label className="block mb-2">
            Prompt:
            <textarea
              name="prompt"
              className="border border-gray-300 rounded px-4 py-2 w-full"
              type="text"
              rows={4}
              onChange={handleUserInput}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
      </section>

      <button
        className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-600 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded"
        onClick={sendUserInput}
      >
        Send
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

can someone tell me how i can optimize it.

Comment: *) Delete all the unnecessary lines. You don't have a logo so why importing it?
*) HOOKS always on the top
*) Organize your code. Gather and separate hooks from each other. All of the useState together, and after the useEffect
*) You declared the "apikey", good. Where is the key?
*) Separation of concerns. Maybe even creating the communication with ChatGPT as a hook